# Java HttpClient doesn't keep TCP connection alive with HTTP/1.1 version

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, tomcat, tcp

I configured `java.net.http.HttpClient` as shown below:

```java
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1).build();
```

Also, I have a simple `Spring Boot (Tomcat)` HTTP server, which is running on the `8080` port. For each request, I check incoming headers in a controller and the number of `TCP` connections using the next command: `lsof -i -P | grep "TCP" | grep "8080"`.

1. When I make a `GET` request from `client` then exactly one `TCP` connection is created for each request. Incoming headers don't have any information about `keep-alive`
2. When I try to set `keep-alive` header directly I got the [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315472/how-to-customise-host-header-in-java-http-client).

```
HttpRequest req = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                             .setHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
                             .uri(uri)
                             .build();
```

3. When I make a `GET` request from a browser `(safari)` then the browser adds `keep-alive` headers to each request and only one `TCP` connection is created for multiply requests (as expected).
4. When I set version HTTP/2 and make the request from the client then only one `TCP` connection creates for all requests (as expected):

```java
 HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2).build();
```

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677261/how-to-keep-httpclient-connection-keep-alive) - both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 have `keep-alive` property which is enabled by default, but as you can see from the examples above it doesn't work for HTTP/1.1 in my case.
Does anyone know how to configure `HttpClient` properly? Or maybe, I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: *" Incoming headers don't have any information about keep-alive"* - for HTTP/1.1 the default is keep-alive, unless explicitly specified otherwise. Thus a HTTP/1.1 response with no Connection header is equivalent to having a Connection header of keep-alive.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you! I've never known about it. You are absolutely right. Explanation on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection). Do you have any idea why then it creates TCP connections for each request (and why a browser doesn't do the same)?

Comment: Hard to tell due to missing code for the actual request handling. But have a look at [How to get persistent HttpConnection with Apache HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053067/how-to-get-persistent-httpconnection-with-apache-httpclient). Note that with HTTP/2 multiple requests are sent in parallel over the same TCP connection while with HTTP/1.1 only one after the other. Thus you need to make sure to end the previous one properly before starting the next - otherwise it will need to create a new TCP connection.

Comment: Thank you, I'm working with `java client` instead of `apache client`, and the StackOverflow question (which you suggest) actually doesn't fit my problem. Also, I've disabled parallel run, as you suggested, but the client with version HTTP_1_1 still creates a new TCP connection for each request.